# How to find all users except current user with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to display a list of users but the logged-in user shouldn't see himself in the list. I can't make the request to get all users but current user to work.

```
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await User.find({ user: { $ne: req.user.id } }).select([
            "email",
            "username",
            "bio"
        ]);

        res.json(users);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Servor Error");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This request below gets the current user and it works.

```
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            user: req.user.id
        });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "There is no profile for this user" });
        }
        res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Servor error");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `_id` field inside the query filter instead of `user`:

```js
const users = await User.find({ _id: { $ne: req.user.id } }).select([
            "email",
            "username",
            "bio"
        ]);
```

Comment: According to OP the `user` field match to get the logged-in user works. Why `_id`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was wondering the same as @ambianBeing actually, thats why I couldnt make it work

Comment: @ambianBeing you may be right, but  let's see if this works for OP: